# Share Eclipse keyring file between 2 computers

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse with Remote Systems plugin to access multiple SSH server.

Using a dropbox account, I'm sharing the profiles directory to my home pc, and that is working fine (if I add a new server on my office pc, it gets copied also to my home pc, and the other way too).

But my passwords won't copy. I know that Eclipse is using a keyring file, so I used the following command line:

```
C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -eclipse.keyring "C:\eclipse\shared\keyring.dat" -eclipse.password "c:\eclipse\shared\psw.txt"
```

I see that when I add or change a password, the file gets copied to dropbox, but my other pc (with the same command line) won't recognise the saved passwords.

Why is this happening?

Side note: the eclipse workspace was also copied entirely the first time i've installed eclipse at home

**Update:** the command line is correct, the file is updated, and looking at Eclipse settings, under *Remote Systems -> Passwords* I can see the passwords in both computers, but it's like they are not associated with the profile, since when expanding a filter, the password prompt pops up.

Comment: Try to use the argument `-keyring` instead of `-eclipse.keyring`, together with the `-password` argument.

Comment: @harrymc doesn't work: without `eclipse.` the default location for the keyring is used and my file is ignored

Comment: And if you use both ?

Comment: it asks me to set a master password, so my password file is also ignored. what I think is happening is that the keyring file can contain multiple keyrings for each computer/user account and it uses some other info to access the file, not only the password

Comment: The master password is used to encrypt the other passwords and is required. Otherwise a random password is used which is known only on one computer.

Comment: Have you verified that dropbox is working correctly? Checking that the password & keyring files are changing throughout the copy process?

Comment: @rastaBob yes, the file is changing in both directions

Comment: Do you manage to use the keyring on more than one computer? If no, see my above comment. If yes, is your problem really that updates from one computer are not recognized on the 2nd one?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Again: Have you ever managed to correctly use the dropbox keyring on more than one computer?

Comment: yes, the keyring works and eclipse can show me the usernames inside, but remote system explorer just refuses to use them if they come from the other pc

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the argument -keyring instead of -eclipse.keyring, together with the -password argument.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, it would be better to also include the actual complete command.